# Do AppIndicators work on Xubuntu?

Tags: indicator, xubuntu

I don't have access to an Xubuntu install right now so I thought I'd just ask this here.

Does Xubuntu (or more specifically, the XFCE panel) support AppIndicators?

I'm porting an application to use them and I am curious to know if my app will work there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should definitely be possible because the indicators are made to be cross-platform.

It appears that someone has developed an xfce panel applet to do provide this functionality:
http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-indicator-plugin

It doesn't seem very mature though - its at version 0.0.1, which is the first stable release. It is not packaged but is available as source code.

Comment: Also, libappindicator should fall back to using the default system tray (become a normal GtkStatusIcon) if the indicator applet is not installed.

Comment: There have since been some updates to that project.

Comment: In Xubuntu 14.04, `xfce4-indicator-plugin` supports 3 types of indicator: Messages, Sound, Power (partial). Newer releases seem to have better support for Indicator Power and Indicator Network.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is an [XFCE panel plugin that should make it possible to put most GNOME panel applets into the XFCE panel](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xfapplet-plugin).
2. The indicator applet is a GNOME panel applet.

Maybe you can try if 1 supports 2?